# Who were the Jedi attending the report on the Outer Rim sieges?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, revenge-of-the-sith

In *Revenge of the Sith*, Anakin arrived late for the report on the Outer Rim sieges. While hurrying in, he passed by five fellow Jedi coming out of the door, and yet a couple on the stairs of the briefing room. Do we know the identities of these Jedi?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The script isn't much help; Scene 79 - 
*ANAKIN rushes into the Briefing Room. By the time he reaches the Chamber, **the last of the Jedi are leaving.** Only OBI-WAN remains at the front of the lecture hall. He is shutting off some holograms and electronic charts and maps.*

Comment: The scene doesn't appear in the official novelisation, it just cuts straight to Anakin's conversation with Obi-Wan; "*But now here was Obi-Wan-Obi-Wan would help him, Anakin knew he would-if only Anakin could figure out the right

 

way to ask …

While he was still hunting for words, Obi-Wan reached him. “You missed the report on the Outer Rim sieges.”*"

Comment: The junior novel doesn't name them *"and even as he pointed out the latest battle zones for the crowd of Jedi and answered their questions in the briefing room."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ran into the [Wookieepedia page of **Melik Galerha**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Melik_Galerha), which states:

> In 19 BBY, the final year of the crisis, **Galerha**, alongside fellow
>   Jedi **Koffi Arana**, **Olana Chion**, **Jurokk**, **Ma'kis'shaalas**, **J'oopi Shé** and
>   **Shadday Potkin**, attended a meeting in the Jedi briefing room regarding
>   the Republic's siege of the Outer Rim. The meeting was presented by
>   Jedi Master **Obi-Wan Kenobi** shortly before the Supreme Chancellor
>   **Palpatine** initiated Order 66, which caused most clone troopers to
>   eliminate their Jedi Generals.

Even the count matches; seven Jedi! So, it looks like the solution to the mystery was at plain sight - as usual in the Star Wars universe. :-P

[image]

Comment: For the record, the article in Star Wars Insider (#137) that the wookieepedia author is referencing doesn't *actually* say that these are the Jedi at the meeting. The writer of the article on wookieepedia appears to have decided that anyone not seen elsewhere in the film must have been one of the Jedi at that meeting. Obviously you can match some of them up visually...